# NSOperation crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsoperation

This crash was not came up every time.
I think the mutableData's address is not valid or multiple thread access the mutableData's address.  It happened in the state of memory low.
Big screen devices are the majority, like iphoneX, iphone8 plus, iphone 6plus, iphone7 plus;
The system version is above 11.0.

crash log below:
11 Thread
SIGSEGV
SEGV_ACCERR

```
0 libsystem_platform.dylib  _platform_memmove + 48
1 Foundation    -[_NSInlineData initWithBytes:length:] + 56
2 Foundation    -[_NSInlineData initWithBytes:length:] + 56
3 Foundation    -[_NSPlaceholderData initWithBytes:length:copy:deallocator:] + 100
4 ZYLite    -[ZYMediaDataSourceDownloadOperation URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] (ZYMediaDataSourceDownloadOperation.m:59)
5 ZYLite    -[ZYMediaDataSourceManager URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] (ZYMediaDataSourceManager.m:261)
6 CFNetwork ___51-[NSURLSession delegate_task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke.207 + 76
7 Foundation    ___NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
8 Foundation    -[NSBlockOperation main] + 72
9 Foundation    -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 848
10 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_client_callout + 16
11 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
12 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_client_callout + 16
13 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
14 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_block_perform$VARIANT$mp + 104
15 Foundation   ___NSOQSchedule_f + 376
16 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_client_callout + 16
17 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 424
18 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_async_redirect_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 604
19 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_root_queue_drain + 588
20 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_wqthread + 1176
```

code below:

```
#import "ZYMediaDataSourceDownloadOperation.h"
#import "ZYMediaDataSourceCacheItem.h"

@interface ZYMediaDataSourceDownloadOperation ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger receiveDataLength;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger lastOffset;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *mutableData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *backData;

@end

@implementation ZYMediaDataSourceDownloadOperation

#pragma mark - super

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.mutableData = [NSMutableData data];
        self.backData = [NSMutableData data];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - NSURLSessionDataDelegate

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
          dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler {
    if (self.responseBlock) {
        self.responseBlock(response, self.object);
    }
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
          dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if (self.dataBlock) {
        self.dataBlock(data, self.object);
    }

    [self.mutableData appendData:data];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(nullable NSError *)error {

    NSData *data = nil;
    if (self.mutableData) {
        data = [self.mutableData copy];

        self.mutableData = nil;
    }

    if (self.completionBlock) {
        self.completionBlock(data, self.offset, error, self.object);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: By any chance is another thread running this class's dealloc method to release the instance at the same time?  You might need to explicitly retain this object (or make it retain itself) until after you call the completion block.